# Vuejs - Passing parameters to functions in dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a function that is bound to a dynamically created anchor element via the `click` event handler. The function takes a parameter, the parameter being an object.

I'm doing this in my component:

```
methods:{
        displayUserTypes(){
            axios.get('/antenna-monitor/pull-user-types').then( ({data}) => 
            {
                for(var i in data)
                {
                    $('#user-roles').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                        data[i].name,
                        data[i].description,
                        '<a href="#" title="Edit" @click.prevent="editModal('+data[i]+')"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> | <a href="#" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
                    ]);
                }

                new Vue({
                    methods: {
                        editModal(roles) {
                            this.form.reset();
                            $('#userRolesModal').modal('show');
                            this.form.fill(roles);
                        }
                    }
                }).$mount('#user-roles')

            }
            )
        },
        created() {
            this.displayUserTypes();         
        }
```

The `displayUserTypes` function populates my datatable. Before defining my `click` event handler in the dynamically created link, everything works fine. Data is populated in my datatable and i can invoke the `editModal` function(which opens a modal).

But i need to pass the object as a parameter to `editModal` function to get the current user object so as to populate the opened modal. But i'm getting a Vue compilation error. Looks as though the object is not being parsed when the dynamically created link is compiled.

Attached is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

Comment: Javascript can't magically concatenate string with an object, you need to use `JSON.stringify(data[i])` to "deserialize" editModal argument

Comment: Got it @AlexanderB. now after doing this, my Action column displays the string inplace of the anchor tag. this is how it looks: `'<a href="#" title="Edit" @click.prevent="editModal('+JSON.stringify(data[i])+')"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> | <a href="#" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'`. any thoughts on this?

Comment: sorry, can't solve the whole issue except [object Object] error

Comment: ok. thankyou for your input. will see where i can proceed from here

Comment: for what you're doing, you don't need to complicate things with jQuery Datatable.  Simply use native vue component to render your table.

Comment: hi @Noogen. agreed. it makes life too difficult. Ditched the datatables and went the native way